# How to use Puppeteer in the main project in an Angular application?

Tags: angular, npm, puppeteer

I have a project in Angular 11 where I want to use Puppeteer for fetching something from a site. However, I have some installation problems.

First I tried to install Puppeteer via npm. `npm i puppeteer` and `npm install --save puppeteer @types/puppeteer` did the job.

Next, I added types and typeRoots into `tsconfig.app.json`:

```json
//... other things
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
  },
//... other things
```

The next thing I did was added a piece of code in a method in an Angular component (`x.component.ts`):

```js
  pup() {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://google.com');
      // do my stuff
      await browser.close();
    })();
  }
```

The last one gives me a bunch of errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\through'

Error: ./node_modules/yauzl/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\yauzl'

Error: ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '...\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'

Error: ./node_modules/yauzl/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '...\client\node_modules\yauzl'
```

Could someone help me with this problem? I've found nothing online where someone uses it in the main project.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: did you resolve this issue? can you guide me?